# generating dmp files from an inproc com dll running in dllhost.exe

Tags: c++, windows, com

I am writing an inproc com dll that runs in the dllhost.exe surrogate, but I see an issue debugging it.

in exe's that I've written, I have a top level exception handler that creates a .dmp file i can load in windbg and then crashes, and I'm unsure of how to do this from dllhost. Is there another way to generate stack dumps from dllhost.exe on a crash? i've seen this page (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/910904), but it seems to involve the component services program. Is there some registry setting for this? Because it's something that will be installed on other computers.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [debugging an inproc com server running in dllhost.exe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541256/debugging-an-inproc-com-server-running-in-dllhost-exe)

Comment: What's the point of repeating the same question?

Comment: it was suggested that i separate that question into 2 different ones, so i made this one. i put a link in a comment on the other one.

Comment: no one answered this half of the question yet. i asked about a custom surrogate last week in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505703/making-a-custom-surrogate-for-a-dll-com-server), but you told me not to make one then.

Comment: Hmm, you can't expect me to memorize names of all the SO users that I helped.  My original comment was based on your remark that you were uncomfortable about COM programming.  Something you omitted in your follow-up question.  Choosing the right approach is ultimately up to you, you cannot assume an SO user is going to make himself responsible for it.

Comment: How are you generating the dump in the filter exception handler right now? Making a call to userdump and passing the context?

Comment: it calls SetUnhandledExceptionFilter.
in the function it sets, it uses dbghelp.dll to make a minidump. it calls minidumpwritedump in dbghelp.dll after it loads the library.

but i have no main function in my dll to call setunhandledexceptionfilter in. i could do it in the constructor of all of my com objects, but i dont know if I can guarantee that will be called in time.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having the process dump itself, you can set up a just in time debugger to run when the process crashes. For older versions of Windows, Dr.Watson is a good one that can automatically generate dumps for crashing applications: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr.*Watson*(debugger)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Watson_%28debugger%29) I believe Windows Vista and later versions have replaced Dr.Watson with Windows Error Reporting (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931673)

A simpler tool to use is Sysinternals procdump (use the -e option to dump on unhandled exceptions): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd996900